# Different default programs for viewing and editing files?

Tags: shortcut-keys, filemanager, default-programs, mime-type, photo-management

Wouldn't it be nice if, say, when selecting a file in nautilus (or any other any file manager), hitting *enter* would open it with a **primary** default application, while hitting *shift+enter* would open it with a **secondary** default application (perhaps defaulted to the primary)?

This way, one could assign a file extension to two different programs, one for *viewing* and one for *editing*.
Think of how useful this would be for .html, .rtf, markdown files and image/video files!

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: If you right-click on the file you will have a menu that offers you to open the file with another application.

Comment: @Jean-Marie Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a quicker solution; perhaps a way of customizing a file manager, in order to do this in one click/keypress.